# Warping of space time by objects

Tags: gravity, spacetime, popular-science

**Note:** This question may seem very silly, because I have never formally studied the physics I'm about to ask about at all, all the knowledge I have is from watching videos on YouTube out of interest or what I have heard. If this question requires some deeper physics understanding, please leave a comment saying so, or recommend something I can read.

Thank you.

**Question:**
I've heard about how objects bend spacetime, which is like a huge rubber sheet, and more massive objects bend it more, so other objects roll down the sheet and get attracted to them, and how this explains gravity. I was very fascinated by this, especially such videos:
https://youtu.be/MTY1Kje0yLg

It was all perfect, till I realised that the only reason this happens in the first place is *because* of gravity, things don't roll down otherwise.

So isn't this circular reasoning? Or is there a giant source of gravity beneath the sheet itself?

Comment: The sheet is an illustration of the warping of space that a heavy object does. It shows a membrane, but real space is three dimensional. In addition it is only really adequate as an illustration when the mass of the test object, the one that "rolls" is very very much smaller than the one that warps the space. GR equations when solved, show that the small test mass is "attracted" , it will move along the shortest path towards the center if it starts at rest. For large enough distances Newtonian mechanics comes out, i.e.m1*m2/r and all the solutions known from it.

Comment: Have a look at http://cosmology-lectures.angelfire.com/notes2.pdf